# How to show users that a new comment has been entered

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a small blog that I am creating. It gets its information from a database. I would like to show the users that are logged in that someone else has just entered a new comment. I have created 3 pages: old_count, new_count, posts. I was going to create a session for both new_count and old_count and subtract them in posts. The result would have been displayed in a div to the user. This idea I have scrapped because both old_count and new_count would have the same information, so the result in posts would have always been 0. What I am looking for is something like Twitter where if there is a new entry, a div appears displaying --1 New post--. I have being looking for a way to do this. Can someone please help me. (Note - please explain script given in full....Thanks In Advance!!!!)

Comment: AJAX polling or websockets or long polling.  That should be a good jumping off point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a timestamp of the last time they checked for content.

then, using javascript, poll the server (SELECT * FROM posts WHERE created_timestamp > {$last_checked_timestamp}

If result > 0 then display count.

Update timestamp.

Comment: Can you please provide me with a small sample of this? Because I am seeing that if I set a timestamp when I last checked then everytime I refresh the page with jquery or ajax then the time stamp will refresh too. I believe!!! Not Sure!!! Please for a sample!

Comment: You are correct about the Timestamp refreshing with the page refresh. This should be normal behavior though, right? when you refresh the page, you set the new timestampt to NOW, and should see all the most recent posts. Answer this question: I visit your site, do you want my screen to update with new posts every 2 mins? Or do you want me to visit the site and display how many new posts since last time i visited?

Comment: I want you to be able to read through the comments with out the page refreshing every so often. This is why I want a small div displaying if any new comments have been entered while you were taking your time reading. when you click on this then the new posts will appear and the whole procedure starts again. I know how to refresh the div with the contents, it's the displaying the new post message I can't get.

Comment: this idea works..Thanks. I create a time stamp as I logged in. then I retrieve all information from the data base and displayed it. I then create a page that will refresh every 10 secs looking for any information that was entered after the time stamp that was recorded when I logged in. I then create a reset page so that when I click on the new posts div, it will then reset the time stamp to the time that the div was clicked on using ajax on the reset page. If this reset was successful it will then reload the div with the new comments.......

Answer (score 0):

The question is: When is a comment a new comment? If it has been created between the most recent click and the current click? Or if the user has not yet seen it?

The easiest way will be to store the "known" comments (e.g. IDs) in the session and check against the currently available comments.

Comment: Storing a bunch of ID's in the session and checking those against another set would be terribly inefficient if the comment count is any significant number.

Comment: @BurninlEO can you please provide me with a sample of this?

Comment: Well - you will have to retrieve the comments anyway to show them. While doing so, you can write their IDs into an array. And you can easily compare this array to another array stored via array_diff(). To store the array in a session, you would simply do ''$SESSION['comments'] = $comments;'' If we're talking about <100 comments with integer IDs the overhead is less then 1KB per user. The advantage is that you can show each user the comments that are new to him/her. If you, however, only want to show the change between the clicks, the timestamp would be sufficient and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to store the login timestamp user. Maybe in DB or in session. Check it against the comment timestamp. 
You have to display notifications for all the comments that have been inserted in the database and stick to following conditions

1. Comment_Timestamp < User_Login_Timestamp.
2. (Current_Timestamp - Comment_Timestamp) <= Refresh_interval

PHP:

```
<?php

/*
    DB CONNECT AND SQL TO SELECT COMMENTS FROM THE TABLE. YOU CAN OPTIMIZE QUERY TO REDUCE THE NUMBER OF
    TUPLES
*/

$current_ts = strtotime(date('m/d/Y h:i:s a');
$notified = array();

foreach($all_comments as $comment) {
    if(strtotime($comment['ts']) < strtotime($_SESSION['user_login_ts'])) {
        if(($current_ts - strtotime($comment['ts']) <= REFRESH_INTERVAL) {
            $notified[] = $comment;     
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($notified);

?>
```

JS AJAX

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "server", 
        success: function(data) {
            /* Data is the JSON Object for new comments for that user */
        }, 
        dataType: "json"
    });
}, <?=REFRESH_INTERVAL?>);
```

Comment: This would mean that if I have, for example, 20 users logged in and one person click to see the new post, this will set the new posts to 1 in the data base. Which tells me that when the DIV refreshes for the other 19 users it will then show them 0 new posts. Am I right? or am I just guessing? No sarcasm meant by this

Comment: Do you want to relate comments to users? So if I log in after 1 year, would I get notifications for all the comments I've missed? Or new comments for a specific time period?

Comment: New comments after logging in. However the answer you provided would affect current users. Like I said I am guessing that it would. I am here because I don't know........so you tell me if I am right!!!!! Or wrong!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestion that was posted by David, I came up with the following solution to the questions that I had asked earlier.

1. I created a timestamp upon login.
2. I then use this to run the search on the database.

The DIV containing this information is being refresh every 10 secs and is a clickable link to a timestamp reset page. The code for this page is as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();

$reset = $_POST['reset'];

if($reset == 'reset')
{
$_SESSION['time_stamp'] = time();
echo "done";//confirmation purpose
}
?>
```

and my javascript that controls the whole show:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#divname').click(function(){
var r="reset";

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "reset_time.php",
data: r,
success: function(html){
if(html == 'done')
{
 $('#divwithinfo').reload(/*my blog page url*/);
}
});
});
});
-->
</script>
```